# ListBox ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas tardes tengo un listbox (`webcontrols`) en `ASP.net` que lo cargo de la siguientes manera:

```
ListPatentesAsignadas.DataSource = patente.RecuperarPatenteFamilia(i, 
Padre);
ListPatentesAsignadas.DataValueField = "Nombre";
ListPatentesAsignadas.DataBind();
```

Necesito que cada elemento de ese control seleccionado pasarle el Id y  su Nombre. Pero al momento de seleccionarlo solo me parece la posición y el nombre. Existe algun forma pasarle los datos a un objeto?

Por el momento logre esto pero sin exito. Me podran ayudar?

```
            for (int i = 0;i< ListPatentesAsignadas.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListPatentesAsignadas.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    entidadPatente.IdPermiso = ListPatentesAsignadas.SelectedIndex;
                    entidadPatente.Nombre = ListPatentesAsignadas.Items[i].ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Muestra el html de tu tabla para poder dar una respuesta completa.

Comment: Este es mi html

Comment: Que tipo de dato retorna el metodo `RecuperarPatenteFamilia()`?

Comment: Retorna tipo Patente que tiene como propiedades IdPatente, Nombre. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de asignar las patentes directamente en la propiedad `DataSource`, intenta guardar la lista de patentes en una variable privada de la clase:

```
private List<Patentes> patentes;
public void nombreMetodo()
{
    this.patentes = patente.RecuperarPatenteFamilia(i, Padre);
    ListPatentesAsignadas.DataSource = patente.RecuperarPatenteFamilia(i, Padre);
    ListPatentesAsignadas.DataValueField = "Nombre";
    ListPatentesAsignadas.DataBind();
}
```

Entonces al momento de que seleccione, buscas la patentes por el indice indicado en la propiedad SelectedIndex del `ListBox`. Por lo que en vez de:

```
for (int i = 0;i< ListPatentesAsignadas.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListPatentesAsignadas.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    entidadPatente.IdPermiso = ListPatentesAsignadas.SelectedIndex;
                    entidadPatente.Nombre = ListPatentesAsignadas.Items[i].ToString();
                }
            }
```

Seria:

```
Patente patenteSeleccionada = patentes.ElementAt(ListPatentesAsignadas.SelectedIndex);
// ahora puedes acceder a cualquier propiedad de la patente seleccionada 
// como por ejemplo patenteSeleccionada.Nombre
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!!!!

Comment: Te sirvio la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" CellPadding="4" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" PageSize="5">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IdPermiso" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListPatentesAsignadas" runat="server" Height="205px" Width="237px"></asp:ListBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnGuitarPatente" runat="server" Text="--&gt;" OnClick="btnGuitarPatente_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAgregarPatente" runat="server" Text="&lt;--" OnClick="btnAgregarPatente_Click" style="height: 26px" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListPatentesDisponibles" runat="server" Height="205px" Width="237px"></asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

</div>
</form>
```